# Got a Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function while updating specific doc inside Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I'm trying to update a specific doc inside firebase v9. It gives me this indexOf error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
    at rt.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1032:1)
    at sa (index.esm2017.js:16038:1)
    at actions.js:136:1
    at Object.dispatch (index.js:16:1)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:3665:80)
    at editFeedback (EditFeedbackPage.js:55:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
```

I found some answers suggesting I'm referring to the non-existing doc in db.
To refer to the doc I'm using `useParams()` to get an `id` for the document.
In `useEffect()` I check if the `id` has a value and it shows that it has, but when I try to pass `id` into `editFeedback()` and use it in `dispatch` it appears to be `undefined`.

I also tried to store this id inside the state,

```
const [feedbackId, setFeedbackId] = useState(null)
setFeedbackId(id) // id from params
```

and then use it inside `editFeedback()`, but it still was undefined.

I guess it causes the problem and it shows me that indexOf error.

Maybe someone see where can be the issue.

EditFeedbackPage.js

```
const EditFeedbackPage = () => {

    const initialState = {
        category: "All",
        comments: [],
        detail: "",
        id: nanoid(),
        createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
        status: "Suggestion",
        title: "",
        upVotesCount: []
    }

    const ref = useRef()
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const { feedback } = useSelector((state) => state.data);

    const { category, detail, title, status } = feedback;
    console.log(feedback)

    const params = useParams();
    const { id } = params;
    console.log("id from params => ", id)
    // id from params =>  TexT99K7xz1Q2a4xv5PF

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const cancelAddFeedback = () => {
        navigate("/")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getSingleFeedback(id));
        console.log("feedbackId => ", id);

    }, []);

    const editFeedback = async (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("feedbackId => ", id);
        dispatch(editFeedbackInit(id, feedback))
    }

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        let { name, value } = e.target;
        setState({ ...state, [name]: value })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setState({ ...state, title: '', detail: "", category: "All" })
    }

    return (
        <EditFeedbackContainer>
            <EditFeedbackWholeContainer>
                <NavbarFeedback />
                <EditFeedbackInnerContainer>
                    <h2>Edit Feedback</h2>
                    <EditFeedbackFormContainer
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        <h4>Feedback Title</h4>
                        <label htmlFor="title">Add a short, descriptive headline</label>
                        <input
                            ref={ref}

                            type="text"
                            name='title'
                            defaultValue={title}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}

                        />

            ---------------------
                        <EditFeedbackButtonsContainer>
                            <EditFeedbackButtonDelete
                            // onClick={deleteFeedback}
                            >
                                Delete
                            </EditFeedbackButtonDelete>

                            <EditFeedbackButtonCancel onClick={cancelAddFeedback}>Cancel</EditFeedbackButtonCancel>
                            <EditFeedbackButtonAdd
                                onClick={editFeedback}
                            >Edit Feedback</EditFeedbackButtonAdd>
                        </EditFeedbackButtonsContainer>
                    </EditFeedbackFormContainer>



                </EditFeedbackInnerContainer>
            </EditFeedbackWholeContainer>
        </EditFeedbackContainer >
    )
}
```

actions.js

```
// edit feedbacks actions

const editFeedbackStart = () => ({
    type: types.EDIT_FEEDBACK_START,
});

const editFeedbackSussess = () => ({
    type: types.EDIT_FEEDBACK_SUCCESS,
});

const editFeedbackFail = () => ({
    type: types.EDIT_FEEDBACK_FAIL,
});
    
export const editFeedbackInit = (feedback, id, err) => {
        return async function (dispatch) {
            dispatch(editFeedbackStart());
            console.log(id)
    
            // await db.collection("feedbacks").doc(id).update(feedback);
            // console.log(id)
            // => also tried this version above
    
            const feedDoc = doc(db, "feedbacks", id);
            await updateDoc(feedDoc, feedback);
            console.log(id)
    
            dispatch(editFeedbackSussess());
            if (err) {
                dispatch(editFeedbackFail(err))
            }
        };
    }
```

UPDATED:
Other methods such as add doc, delete doc, get doc, get all docs are working fine. There's only problem only with edit/update doc.
I was trying to ref the doc as I did when delete doc from firebase, which is working fine.

```
export const deleteFeedbackInit = (id, err) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(deleteFeedbackStart());

        db.collection("feedbacks").doc(id).delete();
        dispatch(deleteFeedbackSussess());
        if (err) {
            dispatch(deleteFeedbackFail(err))
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: make sure db is initialized before using it

Comment: @Wostafa it is. Other methods such as add doc, delete doc, get doc, get all docs are working fine. There's only problem only with edit/update doc. I was trying to ref the doc as I did when delete doc from firebase, which is working fine.